# How to restrict particles from falling forever at the bottom of screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I want to stop those particles at the bottom of screen or prevent them to fall forever below the screen. Code requires to settle all the particles collected at the bottom of screen. Please run the demo below and 'click the particle' text. when the particles are generated they are required to be collected at the bottom.

```js
//-------------------------------- For Squares-------------

var d = document, $d = $(d),
    w = window, $w = $(w),
    wWidth = $w.width(), wHeight = $w.height(),
    credit = $('.credit > a'),
    particles = $('.particles'),
    particleCount = 0,
    maxTime = 10,
    sizes = [
        75
    ],
    colors = [
      '#f44336', '#e91e63', '#9c27b0', '#673ab7', '#3f51b5',
      '#2196f3', '#03a9f4', '#00bcd4', '#009688', '#4CAF50',
      '#8BC34A', '#CDDC39', '#FFEB3B', '#FFC107', '#FF9800',
      '#FF5722', '#795548', '#9E9E9E', '#607D8B', '#777777'
    ],
    
    mouseX = $w.width() / 2, mouseY = $w.height() / 2;

function updateParticleCount () {
  $('.particle-count > .number').text(particleCount);
};

$w
.on( 'resize' , function () {
  wWidth = $w.width();
  wHeight = $w.height();
});

$("p")
.on( 'mousemove touchmove' , function ( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  mouseX = event.clientX;
  mouseY = event.clientY;
  if( !!event.originalEvent.touches ) {
    mouseX = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;
    mouseY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
  }
})
.on( 'mousedown touchstart' , function( event ) {
  if( event.target === credit.get(0) ){
    return;
  }
  mouseX = event.clientX;
  mouseY = event.clientY;
  if( !!event.originalEvent.touches ) {
    mouseX = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;
    mouseY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
  }

 var counter = 0;

   var timer = setInterval(function () {
    if (counter < maxTime) {
      createParticle( event );
    } else {
      clearInterval( timer );
      counter = 0;
    }
    counter++;
    
  }, 1000 / 20);
  
  $("p").
  on('mouseup mouseleave touchend touchcancel touchleave', function () {
    clearInterval( timer );
  });
});


function createParticle ( event ) {
  var particle = $('<div class="particle">' + getSymbol() + '</div>'),
      size = sizes[Math.floor(Math.random() * sizes.length)],
      color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)],
      negative = size/2,
      speedHorz = Math.random() * 10,
      speedUp = Math.random() * 25,
      spinVal = 360 * Math.random(),
      spinSpeed = ((12 * Math.random())) * (Math.random() <=.5 ? -1 : 1),
      otime,
      time = otime = (1 + (.5 * Math.random())) * 1000,
      top = (mouseY - negative),
      left = (mouseX - negative),
      direction = Math.random() <=.5 ? -1 : 1 ,
      life = 10;
  
  particle
  .css({
    height: size + 'px',
    width: size + 'px',
    top: top + 'px',
    left: left + 'px',
    background: color,
    transform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)',
    webkitTransform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)'
  })
  .appendTo( particles );
  particleCount++;
  updateParticleCount();
  
  var particleTimer = setInterval(function () {
    time = time - life;
    left = left - (speedHorz * direction);
    top = top - speedUp;
    speedUp = Math.min(size, speedUp - 1);
    spinVal = spinVal + spinSpeed;
  
    
    particle
    .css({
      height: size + 'px',
      width: size + 'px',
      top: top + 'px',
      left: left + 'px',
      opacity: ((time / otime)/2) + 1.0,
      transform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)',
      webkitTransform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)'
    });
    
    if( time <= 0 || left <= -size || left >= wWidth + size || top >= wHeight + size ) {
      particle.remove();
      particleCount--;
      updateParticleCount();
      clearInterval(particleTimer);
    }
  }, 1000 / 50);  
}





//-------------------------------- For Circles-------------

var d = document, $d = $(d),
    w = window, $w = $(w),
    wWidth = $w.width(), wHeight = $w.height(),
    credit = $('.credit > a'),
    particles2 = $('.particles2'),
    particle2Count = 0,
    maxTime = 10,
    sizes = [
        75
    ],
    colors = [
      '#f44336', '#e91e63', '#9c27b0', '#673ab7', '#3f51b5',
      '#2196f3', '#03a9f4', '#00bcd4', '#009688', '#4CAF50',
      '#8BC34A', '#CDDC39', '#FFEB3B', '#FFC107', '#FF9800',
      '#FF5722', '#795548', '#9E9E9E', '#607D8B', '#777777'
    ],
    
    mouseX = $w.width() / 2, mouseY = $w.height() / 2;

function updateParticle2Count () {
  $('.particle2-count > .number').text(particle2Count);
};

$w
.on( 'resize' , function () {
  wWidth = $w.width();
  wHeight = $w.height();
});

$("p")
.on( 'mousemove touchmove' , function ( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  mouseX = event.clientX;
  mouseY = event.clientY;
  if( !!event.originalEvent.touches ) {
    mouseX = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;
    mouseY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
  }
})
.on( 'mousedown touchstart' , function( event ) {
  if( event.target === credit.get(0) ){
    return;
  }
  mouseX = event.clientX;
  mouseY = event.clientY;
  if( !!event.originalEvent.touches ) {
    mouseX = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;
    mouseY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
  }

  var counter = 0;

   var timer = setInterval(function () {
    if (counter < maxTime) {
      createParticle2( event );
    } else {
      clearInterval( timer );
      counter = 0;
    }
    counter++;
    
  }, 1000 / 20);
  
  $("p").
  on('mouseup mouseleave touchend touchcancel touchleave', function () {
    clearInterval( timer );
  });
});


function createParticle2 ( event ) {
  var particle2 = $('<div class="particle2">' + getSymbol() + '</div>'),
      size = sizes[Math.floor(Math.random() * sizes.length)],
      color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)],
      negative = size/2,
      speedHorz = Math.random() * 10,
      speedUp = Math.random() * 25,
      spinVal = 360 * Math.random(),
      spinSpeed = ((12 * Math.random())) * (Math.random() <=.5 ? -1 : 1),
      otime,
      time = otime = (1 + (.5 * Math.random())) * 1000,
      top = (mouseY - negative),
      left = (mouseX - negative),
      direction = Math.random() <=.5 ? -1 : 1 ,
      life = 10;
  
  particle2
  .css({
    height: size + 'px',
    width: size + 'px',
    top: top + 'px',
    left: left + 'px',
    background: color,
    transform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)',
    webkitTransform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)'
  })
  .appendTo( particles2 );
  particle2Count++;
  updateParticle2Count();
  
  var particle2Timer = setInterval(function () {
    time = time - life;
    left = left - (speedHorz * direction);
    top = top - speedUp;
    speedUp = Math.min(size, speedUp - 1);
    spinVal = spinVal + spinSpeed;
    
    
    particle2
    .css({
      height: size + 'px',
      width: size + 'px',
      top: top + 'px',
      left: left + 'px',
      opacity: ((time / otime)/2) + 1.0,
      transform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)',
      webkitTransform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)'
    });
    
    if( time <= 0 || left <= -size || left >= wWidth + size || top >= wHeight + size ) {
      particle2.remove();
      particle2Count--;
      updateParticle2Count();
      clearInterval(particle2Timer);
    }
  }, 1000 / 50);  
}
function getSymbol() {
  var symbols = "12X34Y5Z+x=-%";
  return symbols.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length));
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:300');
.particle-count {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.particles > .particle {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: white;
}

.particles > .particle.small {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
.particles > .particle.normal {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
.particles > .particle.big {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.particles > .particle.bigger {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

.particles {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  text-align: center;
}

/**-----------------------------------------------------------------**/
.particle2-count {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.particles2 > .particle2 {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: white;
}

.particles2 > .particle2.small {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
.particles2 > .particle2.normal {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
.particles2 > .particle2.big {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.particles2 > .particle2.bigger {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

.particles2 {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
<body>
  <p>Click for particles</p>
  <div class="particles">
  </div>
  <div class="particles2">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope you guys can easily fix this
Thanks!

Comment: Whoa too much code. Just post the required &breif snippet of the code you are facing problem wirh. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: run the demo you will understand the problem i am facing.

Comment: I think you should whittle this question to less specific code, and more applicable to other users. Something like "How to halt animation at bottom of viewport", something similar. As it stands, a moderator *could* edit the question, but that's asking a lot. Try editing to make it easier to read and answer.

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. Furthermore, [you should attribute code that isn't yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44253916/how-to-limit-particle-to-release-from-only-one-object-position-file-instead-of-c).

Comment: @AkashShakya pplace the code in jsFiddle or codepen and provide a link to that . Here show the miinimal code where you are facing the problem

Comment: This code is same code as one my team mate posted yesterday. we are working on a project together so no issue. thanks!

Comment: Neither one of you authored this code. You're already removing particles that fall beyond the bottom of the viewport...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make something "bounce" when it reaches the bottom of the frame you should check if it is below the bottom of the screen if so reverse the velocity of the particle, dampen its rebound velocity by multiplying it by a number less than one and set its height to be the bottom of the screen- this helps with stutter. For instance:

```
if (top + size > wHeight) {
  speedUp = -0.7 * speedUp; // rebounds with 0.7 times the velocity
  top = wHeight - size;
}
```

[JSFiddle example.](https://jsfiddle.net/u1906nf1/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: can we make them let be visible when it stopped bouncing?